# Advanced drawing library for C#

Tags: c#, graphics, frameworks, drawing

I’m looking for an advanced noncommercial drawing library for C# with WPF.
My goal is to create a drawing application. Not vector graphic support is needed, only bitmap.

Comment: you are using WPF or simple winforms?

Comment: "My goal is to create a drawing application." What kind of "drawing"? Is user going to draw? Do you need to draw something? Vector/bitmap?

Comment: @Euphoric I want create a bitmap painting application. No vector support is needed!

Comment: GDI+ is a vector-based graphics library, but you can still create a drawing application. It's possible to lock the pixel buffer in a Bitmap object and manipulate the image data directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most advanced non-commercial API's for drawing are going to be DirectX and OpenGL. They are both complex, but you will be able to make them do almost anything you would want. You could also roll your own design that uses an Image and just changes the various pixels manually. You can then draw the image to your window when changes occur. Here is a code example below. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t3sakh9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason why you can't utilize GDI+? GDI+ is an object-oriented vector-based graphics library built into the .NET Framework. It can perform most trivial drawing tasks, including loading, drawing, and saving bitmaps (BMP, PNG, GIF, JPEG, and others), transforms, color matrix manipulation, and blending. It can also render primitives such as lines, rectangles, circles, and n-sided polygons.

It also has support for render operations, and alpha transparency. You can also draw primitives and other graphical constructs using brushes and patterns, like with GDI.

You can find more information about the classes available to you by looking at the System.Drawing namespace, where most of the GDI+ classes are contained:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific, however Graphic Classes in C# has many methods and features to accomplish any Trivial and some non trivial task.. if you need any thing more than that then you have DirectX.